# Delete row with condition stated in j while grouping with by

Tags: r, data.table

I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to achieve the follwing with a data.table: Frist, do some grouping with `by`, then determine for each group if a condition mentioned in `j` is met and then delete those rows where the condition is true.

The rows I want to delete from `DT` are:

```
DT[ , .SD[t %in% t_p1 | t %in% t_m1], by=id]
```

So, to delete the rows from DT I did:

```
DT[!DT[ , .I[t %in% t_p1 | t%in% t_m1], by=id]$V1]
```

Is there something more elegant, esp. without `$V1`(which is not really self-explanatory here) and without grouping on one variable (which is just misued for selecting entries with the same value/subsetting)?

Comment: you can use aggregate functions and `:=` together to compute aggregations and recycle to full dataset, on the second `[` you can filter based on computed columns.

Comment: If you only would like to get rid of `V1` then you can always just name calculated variable by `DT[!DT[, .(idx = .I[...]), by=id]$idx]`.

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand your suggested approach - It seems to me as if it requires computation of a (temporaty) additional column? To identify the rows which are to be deleted I could also use DT[(duplicated(id) | duplicated(id, fromLast = TRUE)) & (t%in% t_p1 | t%in% t_m1), ] ; however, than I cannot make use of .I to get the position in the original data.table, because it just gives me the position in x. Is there a way to get the original position in DT of selected rows in x?

Comment: Duh, I think I got it:DT[!((duplicated(id) | duplicated(id, fromLast = TRUE)) & (t %in% t_p1 | t %in% t_m1)), ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is:

```
DT[!((duplicated(id) | duplicated(id, fromLast = TRUE)) & (t %in% t_p1 | t %in% t_m1)), ]
```

`(duplicated(id) | duplicated(id, fromLast = TRUE)` substitutes `by=` with a single column as it selects all rows with the same value in `id` - not just the (additional) duplicates, but the first occurrence as well)